# What is a rich object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, javascript-objects

I'm learning Express. While doing a tutorial, I stopped to try to figure out why the tutor used `express.urlencoded({extended: false})`. I learned what url-encoding is, and I've read descriptions on the true or false values for the `extended` option, but I'm still not sure why we have to put `extended: false` in this app. I know it's because we are storing input from a form, and that input has to be parsed to be usable in the req.body object. But the best documentation on the extended option says that a true value uses the qs library and allows for rich objects and arrays in our body object, whereas false uses the querystring library which only allows a string or an array.

So, is a "rich" object just a nested object? (Same with array?) And why would we set extended to false?

Comment: You'd set it to `false` if you don't want it or you're working w/ something that doesn't accept/send data like that.

Comment: “Rich” usually means that it *has more stuff*. I.e. it’s not a plain boring object or array, but some augmented type which has additional methods which allow you to do more stuff more easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [qs docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs#readme), you can see what kinds of objects it can parse beyond the usual key-value pairs of query strings.

If you don't want that, the parsing's presumably a lot more complicated than parsing a regular query string, so not doing that extra work should be beneficial to performance/just make your application simpler.

Comment: Thanks. I read the qs docs, but still didn't know why we'd have to put that there, w/that option. Re. express.urlencoded({extended: false}), the tutor'd said, "all this is doing is it is telling our application that we want to take these forms from our email and password and we want to access them inside of our request variable inside our post method." I think maybe what Dave wrote,  "if you're working w/something that doesn't accept/send data like that" might make sense. I'd been thinking about it from a "what does this do" perspective, but a "what does it DISABLE" perspective may be the key.